# Cassandra AttributeError: 'PrepareMessage' object has no attribute 'consistency_level'

Tags: python-2.7, cassandra, attributes, datastax, datastax-enterprise

This error is not seen every time. When the application runs multiple times we have seen this issue.
Can one help me regarding this?

```
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM hourly_table where mac=? and name=? and processedhour >= ? and processedhour < ? ;'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Extraction/main/CassandraOps.py", line 1229, in selectConcurrent
    select_statement = session.prepare(sql_query)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2496, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare (cassandra/cluster.c:43515)
    raise
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2493, in cassandra.cluster.Session.prepare (cassandra/cluster.c:43365)
    query_id, bind_metadata, pk_indexes, result_metadata, result_metadata_id = future.result()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4198, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:80578)
    raise self._final_exception
AttributeError: 'PrepareMessage' object has no attribute 'consistency_level'
```

Expected Query:

```
select called_station_id,unixtimestamp,acct_session_id,nas_port_id,session_mac,acct_input_octets,acct_output_octets from cdr_sessionterminated where called_station_id = '421888800011' and unixtimestamp>='2021-07-28 11:00:00Z'and unixtimestamp < '2021-07-28 12:00:00Z';
```

Code:
`

```
sql_query = "SELECT {} FROM {} where called_station_id = ? and unixtimestamp >= '{}Z' and unixtimestamp < '{}Z' ;".format(columns, table, timeUnitFrom, timeUnitTo)

select_statement = session.prepare(sql_query)

statements_and_params = []

for row in queryFrame.itertuples(index=False):

    row = list(row)

    params = ()

    for column in range(0, len(columnList)):
            params+=(row[column],)
            statements_and_params.append((select_statement, params))

results = execute_concurrent(session, statements_and_params,raise_on_first_error=False, concurrency=10)
```

`

Error:

```
'PrepareMessage' object has no attribute 'consistency_level'
```

Note:

```
 I'm not getting this error always. it's not even consistent for the past 24 hours I got this error twice.
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Python coding issue and not specific to Cassandra.

I would suggest that you review your code particularly where you are creating prepared statements and check for errors. For example, it's likely that sections of the code are not indented correctly leading to the error you posted. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, @Erick Ramirez. let me check it once.

Comment: it worked for me. it was a code issue. Thank you @Erick Ramirez

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue @Erick. I attached the code details. can anyone review it?